# PHP + MariaDB - Make PHP show MySQL results once?

Tags: php, mysql

I am pretty new to web development, with all the new stuff I had to link together. I am trying to make this simple MySQL + PHP script work, however, I seem to get results repeated 2 times.

**This is my result.**

```
Array
(
     [0] => Matthew John
     [fullname] => Matthew John
)
```

**Here is the entire database and its one table.**

```
DB    : Milky
Table : userinfo

id | fullname     | username    | email
---+--------------+-------------+----------------------
1  | matthew john | matierpixel | matierpixel@gmail.com
```

**The code I used is from W3Schools.**

```
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "********", "milky");
$query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT fullname FROM userinfo");

$result = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
print_r($result);
```

I do not if this helps to get the answer, but I am using a nginx server, with PHP linked as FastCGI.

Thanks,
matierpixel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're not defining the resulttype `mysqli_fetch_array` might give you both a numeric and associative array. You could use `mysqli_fetch_assoc` instead to only get the latter.

Comment: Hah, I totally misunderstood what the OP meant by the result being repeated.

Comment: Only in 10 minutes, you answered my question. This is why StackOverFlow is awesome.